# Return something other than nil from a method sent to nil

Tags: objective-c, null, nsstring, message-passing

This is probably impossible with a category, but just in case it is doable, I wanted to find out.

I wrote a category on `NSString` and  I have a category method that parses a comma delimited string into an `NSArray` cleaning up extra commas and spaces, and trimming the ends... so more comprehensive than the built-in method of similar functionality.  Here's the rub though... what if the string is `nil`?  Is there any way I can return an initialized `NSArray` with 0 objects instead of returning `nil`?

The scenario would go something like this...

```
NSArray *parsed = [someString parseStringIntoArray];
```

... assume `someString` is `nil`.  Can I somehow get an initialized array out of this?

Obviously there are ways to work AROUND this, but keeping it clean and succinct, and using the category method... is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But yes, if you make some changes:

Since you call a instance method, this won't work. When you send a message to `nil` (aka call a method on a nil object) you will always get `nil`.
This is the key concept of nil itself.

You can for example add a class method and in this class method, you can then test against `nil` and return an empty array instead:

```
+ (NSArray *)parseStringIntoArray:(NSString *)string {
    return [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","] ?: @[];
}
```

or you can simply use, what `NSString` has built in:

```
NSArray *parts = [@"foo,bar,la,le,lu" componentsSeparatedByString:@","] ?: @[];
```

**EDIT**

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString:` will still result in `nil` if the receiver is `nil`.

Comment: Then your second line is irrelevant. _focus_

Comment: Whoa nelly... hold on... you said no, but then in your edit, it looks like that would actually work if the method is defined as a class method.  Is that correct?

Comment: That would work if the call becomes `[NSString parseStringIntoArray:myString]`, but it's no different than doing the `nil` check inline at the call site, @LogicsaurusRex.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: *thanks* for your feedback, I did some changes =) And yes, I'd personally prefer the inline variant with native methods

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex sorry for being a Nonlogicodontosaurus

Comment: @Julian  The reason I didn't use the built in functionality is because I'm doing more scrubbing behind the scenes.  I'm removing empty spaces, extra commas, etc, to make sure I get a really clean, solid list.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex Okay, absolution granted

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to return anything from a message sent to `nil`. That is baked into the very core of the runtime: [`objc_msgSend()` is responsible for this behavior](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-tour-part-3-the-fast-path/).

If the receiver is `nil`, `objc_msgSend()` resolves the expression to the appropriate 0 value for the return type of the method.

You will have to test for `nil` either before or after and change the value of the array manually.

(Incidentally, the fact that this is a category method is irrelevant.)